# Stop and hide activity indicator when webpage has loaded

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm having problems getting my activity indicator to stop and hide once my webpage loads in my app.  Here is my code with the activityIndicator.stopAnimating() removed because everywhere I put it in my code prevents the indicator even starting.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class AppointmentsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork(){

            webViewDidStartLoad(webView: myWebView)

            let url = URL(string: "https://www.posebeautysalon.com/appointment")!

            myWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))

        }
        else{
            print("Internet Connection not Available!")

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "Make sure your device is connected to the internet.", preferredStyle: .alert)

            // Create the actions
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
                UIAlertAction in
                NSLog("OK Pressed")

            }

            // Add the actions
            alertController.addAction(okAction)

            // Present the controller
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }

    func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        NSLog("The webview is starting to load")
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        activityIndicator.isHidden=true;
        NSLog("The webview is done loading")
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should be enough to just use your `activityIndicator` within `webViewDidStartLoad` and `webViewDidFinishLoad`.
 No need to hide it, just make sure it has the `hidesWhenStopped` attribute to true. By either setting this in your Storyboard or `activityIndicator.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped` within the `webViewDidFinishLoad`.

```
func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView : UIWebView) {
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView : UIWebView) {
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`UIWebViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebviewdelegate), as you’re trying to use it’s functions but aren’t inheriting and assigning its class.

Although you should look into [MVC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), you can just have your view controller be your delegate.

```
class AppointmentsViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
  ...
  func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myWebView.delegate = self
    ...
  }
}
```

After that your `webViewDidStartLoad` and `webViewDidFinishLoad` functions should work as expected.